# Magento 2.2.8 Cart Price Rule with Country doesn't work when Coupon Code used

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.8

I have Magento 2.2.8 with a live and working store. We can not seem to make Cart Price Rules that have a Country/Region/Postcode/Shipping Method work when coupon codes are used. when remove that condition (regional restriction) and the rule works fine. Now if I leave that condition and do not use that coupon code, it also works properly.

Please suggest How can I go about that troubleshooting ? I have no conflicting rules that I can see.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get the solution?